# Combine window.location.reload () with following functions

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for a way the command window.location.reload (); to combine with subsequent actions. Can someone help me to hang these together?
Individually the actions work. This is my JQuery code:

```
// Page reload
window.location.reload();
// delete active classe
$("#panel-'. $formKey[1] . ' button").on("click", function (e) {
    // close active panels
    $("content .accordion .accordion-navigation.proposal-90").removeClass("active");
    $("content .accordion .accordion-navigation a#panel-90").removeClass("active");
    $("content .accordion .accordion-navigation div#panel-90").removeClass("active");
    $("content .accordion .accordion-navigation a#panel-90").removeClass("choose");
    $("content .accordion .accordion-navigation a#panel-").addClass("notchoose");
    // open evaluation panel
    $("content .accordion li#96.accordion-navigation").removeClass("hidden");
    $("content .accordionli#96.accordion-navigation").addClass("active");
    $("content .accordion .accordion-navigation a#panel-96").addClass("active");
    $("content .accordion .accordion-navigation div#panel-96").addClass("active");
});
```

Many thanks for your help.
m.orange

Comment: When you call `location.reload()` you are **reloading** your page, as if the user had clicked the browser's reload button. This wipes everything and loads a fresh new copy of the page. Any JavaScript after the `location.reload()` call will not be executed, because the current page is now gone. Can you can describe what you're actually trying to do?

Comment: Hi Michael, I have built a form which updates the page after submitting, so that the user can then see the inputs elsewhere below. The form should be closed for better clarity.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you're doing an Ajax submit with a `preventDefault()` to suppress the normal action of loading the new page? Then instead of trying to reload the current page, you will need to update the page yourself as needed, without the reload call.

Comment: Hi Michael, japp you interpreted it correctly. I thought so, but hoped it works without. Thank you for your assessment.